# PHP ldap_get_entries() return count=zero

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I am trying to authenticate users' login against LDAP(Server is Mac El Capitan).

I can successfully connect and bind to the ldap server.

I can search and sort the result.

**But when I perform "ldap_get_entries",I received "Zero" entry.**

I've tried everything from StackOverFlow to Google's second page. 

Any Suggestions or idea why this might be happening?

MY CODE -

```
    <?php
    session_start(); // Starting Session
    $error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else
    {
    $usernameLogin=$_POST['email'];
    $passwordLogin=$_POST['password'];
    $username  = stripslashes($usernameLogin);
    $password  = stripslashes($passwordLogin);
    echo "User name is ".$username;
    echo "</br>";
    $ldapUser  = "uid=xxxxxx,cn=users,dc=dns1,dc=xxxxxxxx,dc=com";
    $ldapPass  = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    $url       = "ldap://dns1.xxxxxxx.com:389";
    $ldap      = ldap_connect("$url") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
    $baseDN    = "cn=users,dc=dns1,dc=xxxxxxxxx,dc=com";      
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
    $bind      = ldap_bind($ldap, $ldapUser, $ldapPass);

    if($bind) {
        echo "Connected To LDAP";
        echo "</br>";
        $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
        echo "Filter = ".$filter;
        echo "</br>";
        $result = ldap_search($ldap,$baseDN,$filter) or die("Could not search.");
        echo "Result = ".$result;
        echo "</br>";
        $sort = ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"uid");
        echo "Sort = ".$sort;
        echo "</br>";
        $number = ldap_count_entries($ldap, $result);
        echo "Count Entries = ".$number;
        echo "</br>";
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";
        echo "Info = ".$info;
        echo "</br>";
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($info); echo '</pre>';
        echo "</br>";
        $fentry= ldap_first_entry($ldap, $result);
        echo "First Entry = ".$fentry;

         for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
            {
                if($info['count'] > 1)
                    break;
                echo "<p>You are accessing <strong> ". $info[$i]["sn"][0] .", " . $info[$i]["givenname"][0] ."</strong><br /> (" . $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0] .")</p>\n";
                echo '<pre>';
                var_dump($info);
                echo '</pre>';
                $userDn = $info[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]; 
            }

        ldap_close($ldap);

    }
    else{
        echo "Cannot Connect To LDAP.";
    }


    }}
    ?>
```

[image: Echo Results On Browser.]

I can connect - bind - search But "ldap_get_entries()" returns zero.

Comment: if you search for that username do you get anything you are looking in sAMAccountName not the email field in AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You can skip the `or die "Could not connect to LDAP Server"` as that will almost never happen. `ldap_connect` only checks the parameter for syntactical correctness and does **not** actually connect to the server. The actual connection happens on the first call to the server which usually is `ldap_bind`. That's why conncetion issues often surface on `ldap_bind` and not on `ldap_connect`.

Second: Where did you get `samAccountName` from? That's a field that's usually used by ActiveDirectory. In Apples OpenDirectory the user is usually identified by the `uid`-attribute. So your filter should be `sprintf('uid=%s', $username)`.

Third: I doubt that only Users in the group "Open Directory Administrators" are allowed to *bind* agains the LDAP. They for sure are the only ones allowed to *edit* the directory but every other user can *bind* as well.

Fourth: `ldap_sort` is deprecated by now. It's not sorting on the server side but on the client side. So only the returned results are sorted. When you have paged results that means that - even though you sorted the result - there still will be entries that would fit right in between your results. I'm currently working on a way to use server-sided sorting but that relies on the feature to be available on the server. So you can use ldap_sort but you can also implement your own sorting on the result set.

So change the filter to `uid=$username` and you'll get the expected results. The `mail` attribute might also contain the full email-address and might therefore then fail! You can also adapt the filter to search more than one field. Have a look at [this slide](http://rawgit.com/heiglandreas/slidedeck/master/LDAP%20-%20what%20was%20that%20again%3F/20150927%20-%20bgphp/index_online.html#/30) for short examples.

Comment: Yes,you are correct.
2. Every other users can bind as well. I tested it out yesterday and failed. But I test today and every other users can connect as well. 
The rest,I'm still trying out. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I used "mail" instead of "sAMAccountName". 
Here's the details -

1 ) From

```
    $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
```

to

```
    $filter="(mail=$username)";
```

2 ) From

```
     $sort = ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"uid");
```

to

```
    $sort = ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"mail");
```

That's it. 
Lessons learn from here - 

 Use "LDAP Admin Tool" or some sort of LDAP Tool to understand the structure of your LDAP environment before jumping into coding. Big lesson learnt.